# Making space at the top of a textarea is introducing a syntax error when applying the text generated to a field

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am getting a syntax error when reading text back from an xml file.

The data extracted to create the xml was saved in the database after using the following code to add a couple lines in front of a message to allow a reply to typed at the top of a textarea.

```
$('#message_Text').val(function(index, old) { return '\n\nOriginal Message:\n ' + old ; });
```

This xml created is

```
<selector>$("#message_Text")</selector>
<message>.attr("value","This is a reply Original Message: Hi There")</message>
```

The console reports

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

$("#message_Text").attr("value","This is a reply
```

I have tried this with and out the newline \n it makes no difference.

However if I remove the function and just appended a message to the end of the text the syntax error disappears.

So is there something being added to the textarea when attempting to make space at the top of the textarea?

**EDIT**

I made a mistake in my original tests I had left the last \n in and this was causing the problem.

So the question I am now seeking to answer is -

I can replace the \n with 
 when writing to the database and this removes the syntax error BUT of course the textarea does not retain it's layout.

Obviously I now see:

> `Test with newline stripped.<br/><br/>Original Message: <br/>Hi There`

I could of course just strip them out completely.

But I really want a method of including them in the XML and retaining the format of the message. .... I think I will attempt to escape the \n perhaps \n and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have it.

So to introduce the lines at the top of the textarea you do need to use \n

but \n causes a syntax error when attempting to write back to the textarea.

So before wrting to the database in the php added escape the \n with \\n

> $message->set_Message(str_replace(chr(10), '\\n', $_POST['msg']));

This when read back from the xml this correctly created the message

> Attempt with escaped newlines.
>
> Original Message:
>
> Hi There